# Subscript out of range: '[number: 1]' while using jqPlot

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jqplot

Working with some legacy speghatti code with very limited knowledge.

There are two different charts `jqPlot` . First chart represnts Total number of countries in each YearMonth. Second chart would represent all the country name and there distinct number. For 2nd Chart the number of each country will always be 1, however the countries themselves will be one or more.

[image]

1st chart (as above) is generated correctly and selecting one BAR from the chart query returns correct name for the countries. But problem occurs while plotting the second chart. Gives error. What am I missing?

```
ERROR : Subscript out of range: '[number: 1]'
```

The following piece of code creates `JSON`  through an `AJAX`  call a  nd sends to the Jquery function to create a Chart.

```
' Create categories
cat="["
for i = 0 to recCount
if i<>0 then cat=cat&"," end if 
cat=cat&""""&data(0,i)&""""
next
cat = cat & "]"
DebugWrite("jsonCat:" & cat)

startYear= ymStart \ 100
startMonth=ymStart mod 100

periodMonths=25
json="[["
y=startYear
m=startMonth

for i=0 to recCount
DebugWrite("recCount:" & recCount)

if i<>0 then json=json&"," end if ' separator for all but first
json=json&"["&i+1

if data(1,i)<>0 then ' check if there are records to prevent / 0
    json=json&","& data(1,i)&","""&data(1,i)&""","""&data(0,i)&"""]" '<<<<<THIS LINE CREATING PROBLEM>>>>>>>>>
else
json=json&",0,""n=0""]" ' put empty json data if no records 
end if

 next
  json=json&"]]"

 ' clear data array, information now in JSON
set data = nothing
```

The query for the DATA is as follows:

```
detLevel="Country"
sqlWhere="1=1"

            strSQL = "SELECT "&detLevel&" from"&_
            " (SELECT "&detLevel&",COUNT(Distinct c.Country) as CountryCount"&_
            " FROM BIDashboard.dbo.ISO c"&_
            " WHERE ym is not null AND ym="&ym&_
            " AND "&sqlWhere&" GROUP BY "&detLevel&") as x"&_
            " WHERE "&detLevel&" IN (SELECT DISTINCT "&detLevel&" FROM dbo.ISO)"&_
            " ORDER BY 1"
```

Comment: Erm, where's the Javascript?

Comment: Actually figured out that the problem was in the SQL query. So going to remove this post.

Comment: Don't delete the post. Write up the solution as an answer to this question. May help someone else in the future.